# Error accessing value from another model (null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm declaring in my expense template a credit card field like this:

```
class ExpenseModel {
.
.
  CreditCard? creditCard;
.
.
```

When I try to access some information to display on the screen, I get:

> null check operator used on a null value

I'm trying to get it this way:

```
expenseModel.creditCard!.description
```

What's the best way to get value?

I appreciate any comments!

Comment: It means that the `creditCard` value is not set when you are trying to get it (with `expenseModel.creditCard!.description`). As to why that is, we cannot answer from what you have shared, we would need more information